# Parameterized Remote Trigger is blocking the job until the remote job is triggered

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have two jenkins (Jenkins A and Jenkins B) on different servers. I'm trigger the Job on Jenkins B from Jenkins A remotely using parameterized remote trigger plugin.
Does the Job in Jenkins A wait until the Job in Jenkins B is triggered ?
[This is the log from the Job in Jenkins A which is triggering the Job in Jenkins B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHV39.png)

[This is the actual scenario happening in Jenkins B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCcpq.png)

What i understood is that if a remote job is already running then the Job in Jenkins A will wait for the remote job to get triggered. is it the default behaviour?

I want my job in jenkins A to trigger the Job in Jenkins B without waiting that means in this case it should put the remote job in queue and marked itself finished.

Comment: Are you using a freestyle job or a pipeline job?

Comment: It's a freestyle job. @NoamHelmer